# What will happen when "Update set a=a+1"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am curiously about what will happen when execute "update xxx set a=a+1 where xxx".

Is there will be a concurrent problem?

Or this operation is atomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new value of a = old value of a + 1. Database takes care of concurrency issues. It is atomic within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we execute a query, it is executed once. Although apart from `SQL`, in general a code is executed once only until some iterating loop is applied to execute it again and again. There are some method in SQL to achieve this like `While` , `cursor` , `recursive in cte`. In iterating loop it depends on your condition that how many times your code executed.

So in your above query it is executing one time only `old value + 1` is assigned to `new value`.